# Java/JPA persist return value

Tags: java, jpa

I have two entities `Question` and `Publication`. Publication has a list of Question.
When i persist a question is all ok, I check on my database and the row is insersed (I'm using MySQL).

Then i need to show the question of that publication, and when I select the questions the question I persisted before is not show.

I do "`Select p from Publicacion`", that returns the publications with all the questions and not the new one. If I stop the sever and deploy again the application web then when I show the question of the publication it appears!

I dont know what is happening, i dont know if someting about memory or something about entity manager.

please im stuck

thanks

Comment: Did you try flush on entity manager?

Comment: After persist, flush http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#flush() or refresh http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#refresh(java.lang.Object)

Comment: I do em.flush() but nothing happens. I do Select q from Question, and it returns the question, but when i get if from the publication it not returns!

Answer (score 0):

```
public T persist(T object){
    entityManager.persist(object);
    entityManager.flush();
    return object;
}
```

Comment: What is this code?  How does it answer the question?  Please edit your answer to explain.

Comment: You can use this code to persist object. The reason that your newly persisted object doesn't  show in your database is because the transaction haven't been flushed yet.  Use entity manger to flush the transaction will let your Neely created object show in dadabase

Answer (score 0):

I think the flush operation is missing, and probably is missing the commit in the active transaction, it sound like when you stop the server all active transaction are committed and there is why you can see the changes after the shutdown.

You didn't show any code. I suppose you are using JPA, so try to flush the entitymanager.
If you are using application managed transactions

```
em.getTransaction().begin();
Changes  the object are doing here.
em.persist(Object);
em.getTransaction().commit();
```

If you are using container managed transaction check the transaction demarcation, to be sure you persist the object before try to retrieve it